# Adding mutivalue columns in a MYSql Update with LEFT JOINs

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have been tackling with this for a few hours now. I have this query:

```
update xcart.xcart_products_lng_en
left join xcart.xcart_products 
    on xcart.xcart_products.productid = xcart.xcart_products_lng_en.productid
left join xcart.xcart_extra_field_values
    on xcart.xcart_extra_field_values.productid = xcart.xcart_products.productid
set `keywords` =  CONCAT(product, " ", productcode, " ",value) 
where value is not null;`
```

At first this did what I expected to, but the way the client has their database set up, it has problems that I can't seem to figure out.

It turns out the table that pulls VALUE is dynamicly generated and ends up looking like something like this.

**Product 1|Field id 1|Product ISBN 

Product 1|Field id 3|Author's name 

Product 1|Field id 2|Shelf ID**

The problem is that when the query I created runs, it only adds the value for one Field ID, and ingores the others, is there anyway to go about doing this? I'm aware of "CONCAT", I'm not sure how to utilize it or if it makes sense to use it in this instance.

~ Traci Wojcik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join derives a table. You need to update an existing table. If you have for example T1, T2, T3 as tables and you want to update T1 based on T1, T2, T3, then you write:

```
update T1
set T1.Field = (select ... from ... where ...)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The joins are just to put the tables together in the query. The way I have it set now, I'm updating T1, after creating a temporary table from T1, T2, and T3, and seting the field in T1 using the data from the temporary table. The reason I have it set up this way is because the data is spread out across all of the tables in my JOINS. Am I doing this the wrong way?

Comment: If you want to update n tables, then you need n updates. I'm almost certain that your approach is not feasible and my suggestion should work.

Comment: I'm trying this but the problem is I can get all of the field values into T1, from t2, but how do I get this to do multiple tables and columns. From my understanding this only lets me update using only one column. (I'm sorrty if this seems like a dumb question, I'm swamped here and a little over whelmed with work today.)

Comment: There is no dumb question, all the questions help us to improve ourselves. The first thing you need to do is to ask yourself exactly where you need to do the update, which rows of which tables should be updated? The second question is: what should their values be? Finally, you need to separate your update into different updates and in each updates update a single table. If I run something like update T1, T2 set col = value where ..., then I'm not updating T1 nor T2, I'm updating the derived table (the result of the Descartes multiplication or join).

Comment: I'm trying to update t1.field1 from t2.field1, t2.field2,t3.field3, and t3.field1. If I do multiple updates, can I run it as one single query adding it to what's already in that field? I need to have the update add to what's already there.

Comment: No, you need as many update queries as many tables you want to update.

Comment: I only want to update the one table. Just the source data is spread out.

Comment: I just  figured this out, it was my line of thinking. It was completely off track. THanks for your help.